# Obtener los primeros diez dias de dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un archivo `.csv` y lo cargue a un dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

def load_bike_data(bike_path=BIKE_PATH_DIR): #directorio donde esta el archivo .csv
   csv_path = os.path.join(bike_path, "hour.csv")
   return pd.read_csv(csv_path)

bikes = load_bike_data()
bikes.head()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es obtener los primeros diez días de la columna 'dteday', es decir del '2011-01-01' al '2011-01-10' para luego hacer otras operaciones con las demás columnas.

Comment: ¿ cómo lo has intentado hacer hasta ahora ?

Comment: por curiosidad: ¿por qué usaste la etiqueta [tag:python-3.x] y no [tag:python]?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' disculpa a lo mejor fue un error mio que no preste atencion cuando lo seleccione.

Comment: @marmurar la verdad he buscado pero no encuentro un metodo o funcion para lo que deseo ya he usado bikes [(bikes ['dteday'] >= '2011-01-01') & (bikes ['dteday'] <= '2011-01-10')] que lo hace pero nose si hay otra manera de omitir colocar las fechas y tambien que lo agrupe en una sola fila ya que necesitare el total de la columna 'cnt' por dia aunque eso ya lo podria resolver asi como esta

Comment: no no, nada que disculpar. Preguntaba por curiosidad, pues veo que mucha gente hace lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

A tu dataframe, pega esto

```
.sort_values(['dteday'], ascending=False)
```

Esto te ordena el dataframe de mayor a menor, y para tomar los diez primeros, pon luego

```
.head(10)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero el dataframe ya esta ordenado, el dataframe tiene que los dias se repiten ya que hay varios alquileres en un dia solo que en diferentes horas, lo que genera varias filas del mismo dia pero diferente hora y otras cosas